# Capture Data Changes from Oracle Materialized View using Debezium Kafka Connect

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, debezium, materialized-views

I successfully added a Debezium Connector for Oracle Database using Materialized View Fast Refresh and got it to work. But I'm facing an issue with the captured data. Whenever I update a record in the table and perform a fast refresh on the materialized view, the data captured in the Kafka topic is shown as a delete and insert, instead of an update. I'm unsure about what I might have missed or done incorrectly. I really need help with this because I've already spent a lot of time searching for a solution, but I haven't found a complete working example. Thanks.

I've managed to set up a materialized view log for all the tables used in the query for the materialized view. I've also successfully refreshed the view using Fast Refresh. However, I expected the updates made to the table to be reflected as updates in the kafka topic, rather than as a delete and insert operation.

Comment: Hello - did you solve this. We are also interested in testing out debezium with oracle materialised views set to do incremental refreshes - I found this if useful? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022455/materialized-view-fast-refresh-insert-and-delete-when-updating-base-table. It would be good to know if you successfully achieved CDC from a Materialized View! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing is missing or misconfigured: a materialized view refresh is implemented by one of two strategies based on the flag used during refrsh:

1. truncate and insert (ATOMIC = FALSE)
2. a delete and insert for each row  (ATOMIC = TRUE)

the first scenario uses two transaction, the second, just one.

Bye
Guido